# How do we express someone does something unconsciously while he/she is asleep?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

See [this cartoon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dgvk_511dGw&t=9s) at 0:10.

A bulldog was asleep.

While cat Tom walked on tiptoe by the bulldog, the bulldog happened to grab cat Tom by the leg by accident "**in unconsciousness**".

I don't know which word should I use, "**in unconsciousness**" or "**in his dream**" or "**on instinctive reaction**" or something.

**How do we express someone does something unconsciously while he/she is asleep?**

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The medical term for this is **[parasomnia](https://www.healthline.com/health/parasomnia)**. If you suffer from parasomnia, you might move around, talk, or do unusual things during sleep. Other people might think you’re awake, but you’re actually unconscious.

The term used by most lay people is **in [his] sleep**. As this [NGram Graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in%20his%20sleep&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20his%20sleep%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cin%20his%20sleep%3B%2Cc0) shows, the expression is reasonably common. Here is a typical example:

> But it was not many minutes before he began to moan and toss himself **in his sleep**, setting Gabriel and Raphael wondering: What has befallen our brother? - *The collected stories of George Moore*

Comment: Note that any possessive pronoun works in place of ‘his’, though third-person personal forms seem to be the most common usage.

Answer (score 10):

[JavaLatte’s answer of “in one’s sleep”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/280266/367) is the best answer to this in general. It is understood that anything done asleep is done unconsciously. It is also the best formulation available to describe the dog grabbing Tom in the cartoon.

However, it is also worth noting the common word “sleepwalk,” a verb meaning

> 1. (intransitive) To walk and/or perform other actions while sleeping; to somnambulate.

<sup>([Wiktionary on “sleepwalk”](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sleepwalk))</sup>

[Per ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sleepwalk%2Cwalk+in+his+sleep%2Csomnambulate&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csleepwalk%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwalk%20in%20his%20sleep%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csomnambulate%3B%2Cc0), “sleepwalk” is much more common than “walk in his sleep.”¹ And using “sleep-” as a prefix is somewhat [productive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Productivity_(linguistics)), that is, we sometimes see other verbs use it as a modifier to also mean that the action is done while asleep. “Sleeptalk” (or “sleep-talk” or “sleep talk”) is common enough to be [the primary title of the relevant Wikpedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleep-talking), for example.²

However, “sleepwalk” is an intransitive verb, and so are the words that use “sleep-” in this analogous manner. That means you can say “he was sleeptalking,” but you can’t say “he sleeptalked the ‘Friends, Romans, countrymen’ speech from *Julius Caesar*,” for that you would say “he delivered the ‘Friends, Romans, countrymen’ speech from *Julius Caesar* in his sleep.”³

Which means that “sleepgrab” isn’t a thing, and isn’t going to be. You can’t say “the dog sleepgrabbed Tom,” and “the dog sleepgrabbed” doesn’t actually make much sense. So “sleepgrab” isn’t a word that’s going to work for English speakers. However, for intransitive verbs, it *might* work, and it may be worth considering such a formulation, seeing if it’s been used before, etc.

1. <sub>And the margin is vast enough that I don’t feel much need to try other pronouns.</sub>
2. <sub>But it is also uncommon enough that Firefox flags it as a spelling error for me—then again, it also does that with “somnambulate,” though oddly not “somniloquy.”</sub>
3. <sub>Note the existence of an idiomatic phrase “one *could* [...] in one’s sleep,” meaning that one has so thoroughly mastered a process and memorized its steps that one need not be consciously aware in order to perform them. Such idiomatic usage isn’t generally intended literally, it’s just a figurative indication of a high degree of skill. In the case of my example character above, we don’t say he *could* deliver the speech in his sleep—we say he *actually did*. That takes it away from the idiom and makes it a more typical, literal statement of fact.</sub>

Comment: While not an idiom per-se, I think the vast majority of people would understand the construct "the dog sleep-grabbed him".

Comment: Yes, I think it's fair to say ***sleep-[verb]*** is a potentially "productive" construction. Riffing off "pocket-dial", I checked Google Books, and wasn't surprised to find [*possibly I **sleep-dialed** and only dreamed up the conversation that followed.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22I+sleep-dialed%22)

Comment: @Kevin Sounds weird to me, but yes, certainly comprehensible.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Ooh, and “sleep-dialed” sounds like a strong use-case for a transitive sense; I can easily see “I sleep-dialed her” and it doesn’t sound “weird” to me like “sleep-grabbed” does. I’ll think about that one.

Comment: I think the key point there is it's "productive". So even if you've never seen some particular combination (such as "sleep-grabbed"), at least you'd probably understand what sense was *intended*. But "sleep-dialed" gains a bit of credibility from pocket-dialed anyway.

Comment: I added a link to "productive"; I don't think even most native speakers are familiar with that meaning. Also, "talk" is itself not transitive. I would consider "He talked *Julius Caesar*" to be even more unidiomatic than "He sleeptalked *Julius Caesar*" ; at least the latter has the unusual situation to justify its unusual grammar. "He sleeprecited *Julius Caesar*" would be even more justifiable.

Comment: @Acccumulation I absolutely agree, reformulating that example has been the big “to do” item that has me hesitating to update this with FumbleFingers’s “sleep-dial” suggestion. Transitivity seems to be a bit of a red herring here but I’m trying to figure out what it *is* about sleep-grab (or sleep-recite) that doesn’t sit well with me.

Answer (score 5):

The closest word is likely "somnambulatory " -- carried out while sleepwalking.

Since the dog was not actually sleep walking, it might be better to say something like

> the bulldog thrashed in its sleep and happened to grab cat Tom by the leg

that specifies *what* the dog was doing.

Comment: Great, but I am wondering if we could say "**snap**", for example, "*the bulldog snapped in the air in its sleep and happened to grab cat Tom by the leg*"?

Comment: Most English speakers probably go through their entire life without using that word to describe a Tom and Jerry cartoon sleep gag.  It begs the question, was the OP asking for a technical term or something simpler?

Comment: @Tom  No, to **snap** means to bite, or at least a sudden, sharp motion.

Comment: I think "snapped **at** the air" would be better. "Snap" can also mean broke under tension, so "snapped in the air" sounds a bit like the bulldog broke in two while levitating.

Answer (score 2):

The sentence could read as follows:

While Tom walked on tiptoe by the bulldog, the bulldog happened to accidentally grab Tom by the leg ***while unconscious***.

You could also use "while asleep", "as he slept", etc.

Comment: That structure would be a bit ambiguous -- _who_ was unconscious, the bulldog or Tom? "the sleeping bulldog, while thrashing about, happened to accidentally grab Tom by the leg" might be better.

Comment: @PhilPerry Did you not watch the video?  The OP was asking about how to phrase the concept of someone doing something "in unconsciousness".

Comment: it should not be necessary to _watch_ the video in question. I'm stating that _while unconscious_ is ambiguous for someone who has not seen the clip. It does not make it clear who was unconscious, and the whole point of the sentence is to eliminate the need to see the clip to understand what's going on.

Comment: @PhilPerry Seriously?  By your logic it's not necessary to read the OP's query either.  You can live in your little bubble if you want.  However, if you want to understand the context of the OP's question, watching the video is essential.

Comment: if you are trying to describe the action to someone who has not seen, cannot see, or will not see the clip; it is necessary to be unambiguous. Your description leaves it unclear who was unconscious. I am most assuredly not living in a little bubble, and care not for insults, so this conversation is at an end.

Comment: @PhilPerry For goodness sake, take the hint:  WE KNOW THE CONTEXT FROM THE VIDEO.  That was the whole point of the OP's question.  It's not an insult, merely an observation.  After all, by your logic, which conversation are you referring to?  You are being ambiguous.  I will act like you do and not read the previous messages and say that it is unclear from the context regardless of it being obvious.

Comment: @PhilPerry Let me put this another way.  Someone says "Look at this clip. " and you do not look at the clip.  Now you are complaining that you do not understand the context because you have not seen the clip.  Do you get the idea I am conveying here, or is this ambiguous as well?

Answer (score 0):

The next words are related with walking while you are asleep: sleepwalking, somnambulism, somnambulation, noctambulism, noctambulation (walking by a person who is asleep)

http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=somnambulation&sub=Search+WordNet&o2=&o0=1&o8=1&o1=1&o7=&o5=&o9=&o6=&o3=&o4=&h=

If the bull dog was not walking, then I'd suggest this phrase: in spite of himself

Comment: hmm, I don't know if I'd say "Spike grabbed Tom by the leg in spite of himself" to express that he was asleep.

Comment: "in spite of oneself" could mean generally "not knowingly"

Comment: "in spite of [one]self" is not generally used to indicate "not knowingly". It would be more of a conscious and deliberate action, _while knowing_ it was not a proper thing to do -- emotion or haste got the upper hand.

Comment: Thx. Oxford Idioms Dictionary for Learners of English : (do something) in spite of yourself  =(do something) even though you do not want or expect to